# How to open a desktop shortcut from commandline

Tags: unity, command-line, shortcut-keys, launcher, eclipse

I created a eclipse.desktop and locked it to unity launcherd , when I double click on it on desktop, the eclipse was launched just like launching from unity launcher. But if I start it from command line by "path/to/eclipse", the unity launcher will create a new icon in the launcher bar.

How can I avoid this? Is there a command to open the desktop launcher just like double click on it?

Comment: I found a way to update the unity icons by "unity --reset" and "unity --reset-icons", it needs reboot, I have not tried it.

Comment: Don't do `unity --reset` first that will not work in latest ubuntu and for older it will reset all your desktop configuration. And neither `unity ---reset-icons` will help in this case. Please include the content of the desktop file in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to make the association between the launcher and its command stronger:

1.) Launch `eclipse` from the command line

2.) Execute `xprop WM_CLASS` from a terminal and note down one of the quoted strings

3.) Edit your launcher with the following line:

```
StartupWMClass=$WM_CLASS
```

where `$WM_CLASS` is one of the quoted strings.

For this to work please make sure your `.desktop` launcher is located somewhere, where it's recognized by the system, e.g. `$HOME/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`.